# Is there a default implementation of graph data structure in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm

Is there a implementation of graph data structure in Qt with default operations for nodes and edges built-in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any Qt graph classes, but there is a nice Boost Graph Library:

More here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/index.html